# Possible way to rewrite multiple NOT EXISTS clauses in a SQL query?`

Tags: sql, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this SQL statement where there are many `not exists` clauses. Is there a way to rewrite the conditions and avoid table same table scan?

```
select col1,
       col2,....,colN       
from tab1
join <some join conditions> tab3
where not exists (select null
                  from tab2 p
                  where <some conditions eg: name = 'ABC'> 
                    and tab1.some_col = tab2.some_col)
  and not exists (select null
                  from tab2 p
                  where <some conditions eg: last_name = 'XYZ'> 
                    and tab1.some_col = tab2.some_col)
  and not exists (select null
                  from tab2 p
                  where <some conditions eg: country = 'PQR'> 
                    and tab1.some_col = tab2.some_col)
  and not exists (select null
                  from tab2 p
                  where <similar conditions>
                    and tab1.some_col = tab2.some_col)
  and not exists (select null
                  from tab2 p
                  where <similar conditions>
                    and tab1.some_col = tab2.some_col);
```

In the above query there are more not exists of similar fashion. since the not exists clause has the same table to be validated against is there a way to club these not exists into a single kind of sub query.

Comment: share sample data and its output

Comment: There will only be an (expensive) table scan if you are missing indexes. If there is any choice between EXISTS, OR and IN, I always pick exists because it has the most chance of performing the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may OR together the various conditions:

```
SELECT col1, col2,. .., colN       
FROM tab1 t1
INNER JOIN tab3 t3
    <join conditions>
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tab2 p
                  WHERE
                      (name = 'ABC' OR
                      last_name = 'XYZ' OR
                      country = 'PQR') AND
                      t1.some_col = p.some_col);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in ( 'ABC','XYZ',PQR'...)` like below

```
select col1,
       col2,....,colN       
   from tab1
   join <some join conditions>
  where not exists (select null
                      from tab2 p
                     where <some conditions eg: name in( 'ABC','XYZ',PQR')> 
                     and tab1.some_col = tab2.some_col
                   )
```